# Nuxt How to remove script tag

Tags: nuxt.js

The project I'm working on requires to switch languages, so I use i18n to to that.
And I'm using the google maps api but there is one problem.

Every time the user switches the language, the google maps api has to change the language too. Here is how I do that:

I use a computed property (this.locale), which contains the current language selected by the user.

If selected language is English then `this.locale` is `en`, and if the language is Portuguese, `this.locale` is `pt`

Every time the language changes, the google's script is loaded with different language.

But there is one problem: The script is loaded more than once, which makes the script to throw an error (You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.) and stops working.

There is no error when the user loads the website for the first time, and the error can be fixed by reloading the site after the user selects a different language but that would be not acceptable.

So what im thinking of is to remove the script tag before loading it with different language.

Can anyone tell me how to remove a script in nuxt?

My current code:

```
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          hid: 'maps-googleapis',
          defer: true,
          src:
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&language=` +
            this.localeCode,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
```

Comment: There is probably a way of saying to the goolg escript that you're changing the language of it since here it looks like it's not aware of that change.

Comment: I have found nothing in the docs. this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        this.$refs.mapsInput), here is how I call the google maps api but it does now allow to pass it a language parameter (that would be awesome), all I could find is that the url is the one that should control the language. I guess loading all languages they have available would be not welcomed by the devs